# How to get the current location of the user?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am setting up a map which will have the store locations nearer to the current location of the user. But I am unable to get that done. I went through the documentation but I couldn't find anything helpful regarding my problem. What I want If I click on the find the location then it should show me the stores nearer to me.

I have already tried putting a static longitude and latitude and it works fine. I want it to be dynamic.

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'THE_ACCESS_TOKEN';

// This adds the map to your page

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
// container id specified in the HTML
  container: 'map',

   // style URL
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',

 // initial position in [lon, lat] format
  center: [78.3430302, 17.449968],

 // initial zoom

 zoom: 14
});
```

In the Center, I want dynamic longitude and latitude value (Current location). So that it will show me the stores nearer to my location.

Comment: Take a look at the Geolocation API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API

Answer (score 10):

Javascript has a geolocation API that you can use without importing additional dependencies, which will provide you with the user's location in terms of latitude and longitude, you can check more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API).

User will have to give permissions to the web app to access to their location. A quick sample of how you can get coordinates in your code:

```
if ("geolocation" in navigator) { 
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => { 
        console.log(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude); 
    }); 
} else { /* geolocation IS NOT available, handle it */ }
```

UPDATE: Incorporating the geolocation code to your code would be something like this (check if it goes as latitude, longitude or the other way around):

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN';

// This adds the map to your page

if ("geolocation" in navigator) { 
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => { 
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        // container id specified in the HTML
          container: 'map',

           // style URL
          style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',

         // initial position in [lon, lat] format
          center: [position.coords.longitude, position.coords.latitude],

         // initial zoom

         zoom: 14
        });
    }); 
} else { /* geolocation IS NOT available, handle it */ }
```

Comment: Hi Oscar

Thanks for the reply. Please let me know how to use the position.coords.latitude and position.coords.longitude value for the center in my above code?

Comment: It should be [longitude, latitude] btw.

Comment: Just as a general FYI - it's typically not a good idea to include your access token in public posts like this. https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/how-to-use-mapbox-securely/#access-tokens

Answer (score 3):

The other solutions are fine, but the easiest way is using Mapbox's GeolocateControl plugin. There's a complete example here: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/locate-user/

After the initial setup it's as simple as:

```
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
  positionOptions: {
    enableHighAccuracy: true
  },
    trackUserLocation: true
}));
```

Comment: but then after locating the user , how would you get his coordinates ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
if ( navigator.geolocation ) 
{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( function(position) {

        var lng = position.coords.longitude;
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;                    

        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYW50ZWxvdmUxOSIsImEiOiJja2d1azl4ZmgwY3dvMnJueGljMnp6YnprIn0.aIRE0Ii2AmWYWCW5Z3cEFg';

        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',          
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
            center: [ lng, lat ], // [ lng, lat ]
            zoom: 12
        });

    });
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
```

```html
<div id="map" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue. The solution is not in the docs of Mapbox (or I didn't find them):

```js
const geolocateControl = new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
  positionOptions: {
    enableHighAccuracy: true
  },
  trackUserLocation: true,
  showUserHeading: true
});

map.addControl(
  geolocateControl,
  'bottom-left'
);

geolocateControl.on('geolocate', (event) => {
  const latitude = event.coords.latitude;
  const longitude = event.coords.longitude;

  console.log(latitude, longitude);
  // Do something more with lat & long here :)
});
```